# Scrolling up until the last item in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to learn iOS development using swift, and I have encountered something I couldn't find a solution for.

I want to modify a UITableView so that I can scroll upwards until the last item for eg. having this:

[image]

I want to be able to scroll up until the last item is displayed on the first row and stay there, not bounce back ( something like this ):

[image]

Or is there any other kind of control that provides me this functionality ?

Comment: You just have to [set the content offset](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/setContentOffset:animated:)

Comment: So right now the problem is that last cell is not able to be showed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
CGFloat rowHeight = 40 /* YOUR ROW HEIGHT */ * [self.items count];
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, rowHeight) animated:YES];
// Here self.items is your datasource array
```

**SWIFT 4**

```
var rowHeight: CGFloat = 40 * items.count()
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: rowHeight), animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to scroll to last row ,
conversation is array you use :

```
long row=conversation.count-1;
if (conversation.count >1) {
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}
```